# Why user_id column is NULL?

Tags: php, symfony

Im trying to create relation between Products And Users. One User has many Products and Many Products => 1 User. The problem is when i add the form to the table "products" column user_id = NULL.

Here is my relation in Product Entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

And User Entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $products;
```

Why the column user_id is always null? Here is the code used to persists products.

```
/**
 * @Route("/products/add", name="create_products")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER') or has_role('ROLE_EDITOR') or has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function createProductAction(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product();

    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        /** @var UploadedFile $file */
        $file = $product->getImageForm();

            $filename = md5($product->getName());

            $file->move(
                $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/images/products/',
                $filename
            );


            $product->setImage($filename);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        $this->redirectToRoute('products');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('products');
    }

    return $this->render('products/create.product.html.twig', array(
        'productForm' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to save these? what does your form / controller look like?

Comment: Could you please show the code on how you persist both entities?

Comment: Here is create product action https://pastebin.com/LuxTDLip Actually, im not sure how can i save the user_id into controller

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used your setter in your Product object to set your user in your controller. That is the problem.

You would need to use the setter like so:

```
$product->setImage($filename);
$product->setUser( $user );


$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($product);
```

The above presumes you have a setter called `setUser`. You also need to create the user or determine the user.

Answer (score 1):

You are persisting a product without a user. You should do something like this:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->setImage($filename);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// here you associate the user
$user = $em->find('\AppBundle\Entity\User', 3); // user with id 3
$product->setUser($user);

$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```